# autocomplete="off" is not working on chrome for select box with no form tag

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox

I have found N-Number of post on this and i tried all. For example: nope, false, and some random number but it didn't work for me. I am not using any form tag but i am using select box and mozilla is working good with autocomplete off but chrome is not working at all.

```
<select name="qty" class="qty" data-id="" autocomplete="off"></select>
```

This is working for mozilla but not for chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Try add each one as needed:

```
autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" aria-autocomplete="none"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This one:

```html
<form action="" autocomplete="off">

OR 

<form action="" autocomplete="false">
```